# Can't bind onpropertychange to a dynamically generated input text

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, input, dynamically-generated

In an ASP.NET project, I generate N number of editboxes depending on a database query result at the launch of my app. Each textbox has an `id="textNid"` with N = 0, 1 , 2...

I understood that I could not play with editboxfor in this case, so I generate some input texts at the success of an AJAX call at the launch of my app.

Something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    htmlToWrite += "<input type=\"text\" "value=\"" + data[i] + "\"" +
                    "id=\"text" + i + "id\"\">
```

...

It displays fine, I can also specify live css properties like color of the font or disabled property.

But I need to assign an `onpropertychange` method to each of these input depending of their id value.

After /many) tries, I understood that `$(document).ready()` would not bind this kind of method to something which doesn't exist yet.

I also read a few cases a bit similar to mine with an "on + delegate" solution, but I can't properly adapt it here.

In jQuery, how would you implement something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        $("#text" + i +"id").on('input propertychange', function () {
            myMethod();
    }
}
```

...in a way which works here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try using '$(document).on('input propertychange', 'idOfInput', function(){ doSomething()})'

Comment: And just like that, that's it,  thank you so much! (cant thumb up yet, sorry).
For those with the same problem, don't forget # in the id parameter:
$(document).on("input propertychange", "#text0Id", function () {
        alert("OK");
    });